# Make fields mandatory when status is complete

Tags: visualforce, controller, pagemessages

I have a status field on contact,when status is complete,remarks should get mandatory..I wrote if condition for this in controller,but it is not taking remarks field as mandatory..how to write this? please help

My code is:
  Vf page:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!con1.Status__c}"  />
 <apex:inputField value="{!con1.Any_Remarks__c}" />
   <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!saveActivity}"/>
```

Controller:

```
public PageReference saveActivity(){
   if(con1.Status__c=='Complete' && con1.Any_Remarks__c==''){
        apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(apexpages.Severity.ERROR,'Remarks is mandatory'));
    }
 insert con1;
}
```

Thanks & regards,
usha.

Comment: Why don't you use a validation rule for this? Much simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return type is missing in if condition. add return null keyword after the addmessage line.

```
 if(con1.Status__c=='Complete' && String.isBlank(con1.Any_Remarks__c)){
    apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(apexpages.Severity.ERROR,'Remarks is mandatory'));
    return null;
   }
```

And on Visualforce page you have to use

> < apex:pageMessages /> tag.

Another way you can achieved by Validation rule, or go to that field Any_Remarks__c and click on edit and check the required checkbox, no need to write apex code.

**Validation rule like this**

```
AND(Isblank(Any_Remarks__c), TEXT(Status__c)="Complete")
```

**if Status__c is picklist field then your validation rule like this**

```
AND(Isblank(Any_Remarks__c),ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Complete")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to show the message in VFP so declare `<apex:pageMessages id="appMessages"/>` and use `rerender` to display that.

Otherwise,`apexpages.addMessage()` will collect the message but couldn't able to display that.

```
<apex:pageMessages id="appMessages"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!con1.Status__c}"  />
<apex:inputField value="{!con1.Any_Remarks__c}" />
<apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!saveActivity}" reRender="appMessages"/>
```

Controller

Use a logic to verify `apexpages.hasMessages()` before performing DML statement, so that you can add other error messages through `apexpages.addMessage()`

```
public PageReference saveActivity()
{
       if(con1.Status__c=='Complete' && con1.Any_Remarks__c=='')
       {
            apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(apexpages.Severity.ERROR,'Remarks is mandatory'));
       }

       //add more validation rule if that is required.
       if(!apexpages.hasMessages())
       {
            insert con1;
       }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return null after checking for validation. This will make your page-messages show up on VF page. As per your current code you are checking and still inserting record.

```
public PageReference saveActivity(){

   if(con1.Status__c=='Complete' && String.isBlank(con1.Any_Remarks__c)){
        apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(apexpages.Severity.ERROR,'Remarks is mandatory'));
        return null;
   }
    insert con1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you pranay jaiswal for the reply,but unfortunately its not working.

Comment: @koduri have you added <Apex:pageMessages/> tag in VF?

Comment: I added this tag in vf page..still it is not working Pranay Jaiswal

Comment: can you edit your code and provide VF snippets as well?